# Gridlines in BoxWhisker Chart with Logarithmic Scaling Function

Tags: charts, logarithmic-scale, grid-lines

Is there a way to use logarithmically-spaced gridlines in `BoxWhiskerChart`? I've attempted manually specifying the gridlines as follows:

```
data = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1000}], {i, 1, 100}];
xticks = Flatten[Table[b*(10.^a), {a, Floor[Log10[Min[data]]], 
 Ceiling[Log10[Max[data]]]}, {b, 1, 9}]];
```

Then, when using `ScalingFunctions -> "Log"` in `BoxWhiskerChart` with these specified gridlines:

```
plot = BoxWhiskerChart[data, {{"Outliers", "o"}}, 
LabelStyle ->(FontSize -> 20), 
AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> {600, 300}, 
PlotLabel -> "Data", 
GridLines -> {xticks, Automatic}, 
BarOrigin -> Left, 
ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

I end up getting a screwy plot like this:
[image: bad gridlines]

Setting both `GridLines` values to `Automatic` doesn't work either. Is this a chart limitation?

Comment: @JasonB. Great, that works!

Comment: You can generate data like so `data = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1000}], 100]` or even this  `data=RandomReal[{0, 1000}, 100]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just hasn't been implemented yet for `BoxWhiskerChart`.  You can apply the `Log` function to the gridlines manually until it is

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, {{"Outliers", "o"}}, 
 GridLines -> {Log @ xticks, Automatic}, BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]